# A strange SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I can't understand the SQL syntax here: `CREATE...` and `INSERT...` are OK, while the last snippet failed, the mysql-client doesn't recognize `let`,`eval` and `dec`. I didn't find any supporting documents. Does it need special command line tool or plugins to execute?

I know that may be a stupid question.

```
create table t1 (
  pk int primary key auto_increment,
  i int,
  j int,
  k int,
  index (i),
  index (j),
  index (k)
) engine=myisam;

insert into t1 (i,j,k) values (1,1,1);

let $1=12;
set @d=1;
while ($1)
{
  eval insert into t1 (i,j,k) select i+@d, j+@d, k+@d from t1;
  eval set @d=@d*2;
  dec $1;
}
```

- Centos 7
- MySQL 5.6.7

Here is the [source](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67432) of the sqls above.

Thank you.

Comment: That's not SQL. I don't know what it is.

Comment: I suspect it's the scripting language for a test framework.

Comment: Probably yes. I have seen this syntax more than once, but failed to figure out how to transform it into sqls here. I wonder that why they provide such test framework instead of a executable procedural here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the `mysqltest` language used by the [MySQL Test Framework](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.1/PAGE_MYSQL_TEST_RUN.html). The syntax is documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.1/PAGE_MYSQLTEST_LANGUAGE_REFERENCE.html).

It looks to me like it's inspired by BASIC and PHP.